# Putty - Automatically closes on authentication

Tags: ssh, putty, remote-server

I'm on a Windows 7 machine. I am using the Putty.exe executable for connecting to my remote machine. I enter the right credentials, and click open. The console pops up with the following and closes with no errors or warnings.

[image]

How do I make it work?

Comment: putty generates some log file. Have a look for it.

Comment: To extend @Jakuje's comment: Under Session > Logging you can specify the location of the log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are describing is trying to log into the shell with a user that is an "ftp only" user (not authorized shell access).

> Go to Control Panel -> Users -> Manage Users, select the "Edit" link
>   adjacent to the user you are having trouble with, and make *sure* that
>   the radio button for "shell" is selected. Submit the form, and wait
>   for it to take effect (usually a matter of a few minutes).

Once the change has taken effect, you should be able to telnet (though, please do not use telnet, as it is insecure) or ssh into the shell without problem (assuming the user/pass is correct).

Comment: I saw this solution in another forum, but I couldn't find the `Edit` link! Where in Windows 7 would you find it?

Comment: Are you users in the system and what is your access limit? Did you check the putty log for error. I would suggest try another terminal like putty application and check your login again'

Comment: `Access limit` - That rings a bell! I am using my employer's machine and have no admin rights. Maybe that's the reason. I used `Bitvise` client and it works.

Answer (score 7):

Check Putty setting: Connection > SSH > Remote command.

Try to tweak or simply remove the remote command and see if it helps solving the issue.